# I want to make dynamic table(with col and rows) base on calendar date

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-datepicker

[image]

Here image how i want to show my table if i write any with date range base on calendar. In angular js.

Comment: Please show what you have tried., Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective is to help fix issues within **your code**. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I have code in my class room computer. I will post my code tomorrow.

Comment: were you able to solve it? I have the same doubt